# InstallAware 9: How can I put selected files into a folder without others being put in automatically?

Tags: installaware

I'm making a setup for this program and I have created a folder with selected features (.dll files) in them. However, whenever I run the installation, it puts the .dll's corresponding .pdb file with it. My problem is that I don't need the .pdb files on the setup, I only need the selected features. If there are any further questions please comment them.

Comment: By any chance do you have a folder in the bottom right box in the files tab under the group setup architecture that is named '*' or something similar?

Comment: Yes, it is there whenever I make a new directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem, the '*' means select all so what you are doing is selecting all of files in that path and putting them into your $TARGETDIR$. If you want a more custom selection delete that and maneuver around in the upper two boxes to select your desired files.